# CSS class - H2 style not showing

Tags: css

I've got this in my .css file:

```
h2.spielbox {
    margin-bottom:80px;
    color:#f00;
}

a.spielbox {
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#aff;
}
```

But in my html file the h2 style is not showing, while the a-style works:

```
<div class="spielbox" style="float:left;width:320px"><h2>Testberichte</h2>
```

Seems i am not knowing something about CSS ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because you have the class applied to a `div`. Do this instead:

```
<h2 class="spielbox">Testberichte</h2>
```

Alternately, you can do this if you want to leave it in the div:

```
.spielbox h2 {
    margin-bottom:80px;
    color:#f00;
}
```

- `h2.spielbox` matches `h2` elements with the class `spielbox`
- `.spielbox h2` matches `h2` elements that are within any element with the class `spielbox`

Comment: Great, thanks. Why the margin still is not shown, is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Cool site. It works here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vzrwK/
Maybe Drupal interfering.
Learning, well i read i book and already made some sites with CSS. But i forget stuff or do it another way, when something does not work.

Comment: @KarlH.: Yes jsfiddle is sort of the de facto demo site, and indeed very cool. Since you said the inline style declaration is working, I would assume that it has to do with other styles being inherited. There are [several](http://www.htmldog.com/) [good](http://www.webdevout.net/) [references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference) out there for CSS if you're interested in learning more. I wouldn't learn by example from any CMS stylesheets, it will be confusing.

Comment: Yea, that inheritance stuff is still pretty foreign to me. I should read something about it.

Comment: Here's one more useful article: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you have set the spielbox class for h2, so you need to type it in h2,

```
<h2 class="spielbox">...</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, works. Except for the margin-bottom. Thought the class would be inherited by the <div> section...

Comment: No success.
Odd, this works,though:
    <h2 class="spielbox" style="margin-bottom:80px">XXXXX</h2>